# How do I access the IApplicationEnvironment from a unit test?

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit, xunit2

How can I access the IApplicationEnvironment from an xUnit 2 unit test?

There are several scenarios where I think I need this, including:

- Read from a non-embedded configuration file built with the unit tests
- Create and write files relating to the unit tests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's not ideal but you can use [the static service locator](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/e937e25ab3453ea86bda13c1297c41011dfda9de/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions/CallContextServiceLocator.cs) to get to it:

```
var appEnv = CallContextServiceLocator.Locator.ServiceProvider
    .GetService(typeof(IApplicationEnvironment)) as IApplicationEnvironment;
```

> I am not sure if xUnit injects framework dependencies in through the constructor and I bet it doesn't. If it does though (which would be perfect), you can just inject it into the test class through its constructor.

Comment: Yeah, I did try injecting it through the constructor, but I didn't know about the static service locator.  And it works! (Not sure how I feel about knowing that there's a static service locator...)

Comment: @MattDeKrey I agree and as you know, they don't advertise that it's there. I am not sure if they will remove it at the end.

Comment: @MattDeKrey opened up an issue for xUnit: https://github.com/xunit/dnx.xunit/issues/30

Comment: Interesting that @DavidFowler had the same request and is solving it the same way.